# Controller and index view Id and name match. .net MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

in my excercise i have such a code in controller

```
 public IActionResult Index(int catId = 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products;
        if (catId != 0)
        {
            products = _categoryRepository.GetCategoryByIdWithProducts(catId).Products;
        }
        else
            products = _productRepository.GetAllProducts();
        ViewData["SelectList"] = GetCategoriesSelectList();
        return View(products);
    }
```

and such code in View

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="categoryId">Filter by category</label>
        <select id="catId" name="catId" asp-items="@(ViewData["SelectList"] as SelectList)" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- all categories --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary ml-1">Submit</button>
```

And i don't really understand how this tags id="catId" name="catId" in view and controller Index(int catId = 0) match each other.

if i delete id="catId" the submit button work, and if i delete name="catId" it doesnt.

does the mvc looks or the argument and name match or how does it works?

Kind regards, Ilya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the mvc looks or the argument and name match or how does it works?

Yes, The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted. Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form. You could check it with f12 network option.

In addition, modelbinding in mvc is also based on name not id.

Answer (score 0):

- id is used to identify the HTML element through the Document Object Model (via JavaScript or styled with CSS). id is expected to be unique within the page.
- name corresponds to the form element and identifies what is posted back to the server.